# Error while loading a fmu in python with pyfmi library

Tags: python, openmodelica, jmodelica, fmi, pyfmi

I have installed PyFMI library and trying to load a fmu created by GT-Suite in python.

I am following this tutorial of jmodelica :

https://jmodelica.org/pyfmi/tutorial.html

```
# Import the load function (load_fmu)
from pyfmi import load_fmu
```

this set gives a warning

```
Could not find cannot import name 'radau5' from 'assimulo.lib' (C:\Users\chinn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\assimulo\lib\__init__.py)
Could not find cannot import name 'dopri5' from 'assimulo.lib' (C:\Users\chinn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\assimulo\lib\__init__.py)
Could not find cannot import name 'rodas' from 'assimulo.lib' (C:\Users\chinn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\assimulo\lib\__init__.py)
Could not find cannot import name 'odassl' from 'assimulo.lib' (C:\Users\chinn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\assimulo\lib\__init__.py)
Could not find ODEPACK functions.
Could not find RADAR5
Could not find GLIMDA.
```

When I try to load the fmu model

```
#Load the FMU
model = load_fmu('AHUdirectRPm.fmu')
```

I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-77df09904b1e>", line 1, in <module>
    model = load_fmu('AHUdirectRPm.fmu')

  File "src\pyfmi\fmi.pyx", line 7899, in pyfmi.fmi.load_fmu

  File "src\pyfmi\fmi.pyx", line 2558, in pyfmi.fmi.FMUModelCS1.__init__

  File "src\pyfmi\fmi.pyx", line 1167, in pyfmi.fmi.FMUModelBase.__init__

  File "src\pyfmi\fmi.pyx", line 45, in pyfmi.fmi.encode

TypeError: latin_1_encode() argument 1 must be str, not bytes
```

Can someone help me with this. What to do?

output of 'pyfmi.check_packages()'

```
Performing pyfmi package check 
==============================

PyFMI version ................ 2.5                           

Platform ..................... win32                         

Python version ............... 3.7.3                         



Dependencies: 

Package                        Version                       
-------                        -------                       
assimulo...................... 3.0                           
Cython........................ 0.29.6                        
lxml.......................... 4.3.2                         
matplotlib.................... 3.0.3                         
numpy......................... 1.16.2                        
scipy......................... 1.2.1                         
wxPython...................... --              Package missing - Warning issued, see details below
pyreadline.................... 2.1                           
setuptools.................... 40.8.0                        


Warnings 
--------

-- The package wxPython could not be found. This package is needed to be able to use the plot-GUI.
```

Comment: What does 'pyfmi.check_packages()' give you?

Comment: Hi @jrhodin, added the output, installing assimulo package.

Comment: pip install Assimulo was giving errors, used `conda install -c conda-forge assimulo` to install assimulo. Updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the pyfmi package with pip is giving the error.All the dependencies have to be downloaded correctly. Installing through conda doesn't require all this. Installed through conda by

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyfmi
```

This has worked well for me

Answer (score 0):

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "<ipython-input-2-77df09904b1e>", line 1, in <module>
       model = load_fmu('AHUdirectRPm.fmu')
   File "src\pyfmi\fmi.pyx", line 7899, in pyfmi.fmi.load_fmu
   File "src\pyfmi\fmi.pyx", line 2558, in pyfmi.fmi.FMUModelCS1.__init__
   File "src\pyfmi\fmi.pyx", line 1167, in pyfmi.fmi.FMUModelBase.__init__
   File "src\pyfmi\fmi.pyx", line 45, in pyfmi.fmi.encode

TypeError: latin_1_encode() argument 1 must be str, not bytes
```

Is due to an issue with the internal encoding in PyFMI and will be fixed in later versions of PyFMI (>2.5).